# Creating multiple tables using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, building

I've got a requirement to build N number of tables upfront using Jquery and to each table, users will able to append/delete records. Has anyone done or seen anything close to what I'm after ? Still learning Jquery stuff...

Comment: what tables are you referring to? HTML tables or DB tables?

Comment: something like http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html?  dl: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically build elements by doing a couple things

```
var row = "<tr><td>"+somedata + "</td><td>"+someMoreData+"</td></tr>";

$("#table_id").append(row);
```

Is this what you mean?

If you want to build a new table, you can just create a table

```
var row = "<tr><td>"+somedata + "</td><td>"+someMoreData+"</td></tr>";

var table = document.createElement('table');
table.id = "newId";
table.innerHtml += row;

$('body').append(table);
```

Comment: Hi @Coding-Freak, thks for getting back, sorry for not providing a detailed problem statement. This is how the scenario will be like: for every Table created on the markup page, a new record for it will be added in the DB(done via the ajax post as the table is created) and for every child record or rows appended to the table, I need to fire another ajax call to the server to link the child record with it's parent.

Comment: You should just post the data to a php page, and update/create/delete accordingly, taking security precautions.

Comment: Hi @Bodman, I'm familiar with Json stuff but it's the markup side I'm struggling with, like creating tables dynamically and appending rows to different tables...all of these has to be done on the clientside using Jquery.

Comment: Hi @Coding-Freak, @Bodman, this is what I'm after on the client-side, built using Jquery : <table id="table1"> add new row <tr><td>test 1</td></tr> </table> <table id="table2"> add new row  <tr><td>test 1</td></tr> </table> <table id="table3"> add new row  <tr><td>test 1</td></tr> <tr><td>test 2</td></tr> </table>

Comment: @Bodman, ahh I see, you've given me enough hints there to get started, I should be able to take if off from here. thks, mate.